# Powermock - mocking org.apache.log4j.Logger? How can I?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I'm wondering what is the easiest and most concise way to mock org.apache.log4j with powermock (and mockito).

I have tried a few approaches (which I won't illustrate here) but have not yet found a way to achieve what I want.  I have created a simple class to test below and I want to call the run method and verify that the log.info message has been called.  How do I do this? I'm sure it's quite easy when you know how!

(I'm using @Rule as I want to run under spring test but that should make no difference).

Thanks a millon for the correct code.

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockRule;

public class MockLog4JTest
{
    @Rule
    public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();

    private static class ClassUnderTest
    {
        private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ClassUnderTest.class);

        public void run() {
            logger.info("Hello.");
        }

    }

    @Test
    public void testLog()
    {
        ClassUnderTest classUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest();
        classUnderTest.run();
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you tried mocking the static `Logger` class? This page shows you how: https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/MockStatic

Comment: I have tried that but I didn't manage to get it working. The above is so simple an an example, I am hoping that somebody will post an answer with the few lines of code to get this working, rather than suggestions (as I have tried quite a few things) - but thanks for that Chris all the same.

Comment: Hm, I'd second Chris' approach to mocking `Logger` in that its static `getLogger` method will return a mocked `Logger` instance. Injecting the Logger instance into the ClassUnderTest is not an option, right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Chris and Fildor are correct to try to mock the Logger.getLogger(). Unfortunately the way Log4J works makes that technically tricky.

Here's the code I came up with (tested) based on your sample above.

#### ClassUnderTest.java

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class ClassUnderTest {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ClassUnderTest.class);

    public void run() {
        logger.info("Hello.");
    }
}
```

#### MockLog4JTest.java

```
import static org.mockito.Matchers.eq;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.rule.PowerMockRule;
import org.powermock.reflect.Whitebox;

@PrepareForTest(ClassUnderTest.class)
public class MockLog4JTest {
    @Rule
    public PowerMockRule rule = new PowerMockRule();

    @BeforeClass
    public static void oneTimeSetup() {
        System.setProperty("log4j.defaultInitOverride", Boolean.toString(true));
        System.setProperty("log4j.ignoreTCL", Boolean.toString(true));
    }

    @Test
    public void testLog()
    {
        ClassUnderTest classUnderTest = new ClassUnderTest();
        Logger mockLogger = mock(Logger.class);

        Whitebox.setInternalState(ClassUnderTest.class, "logger", mockLogger);

        classUnderTest.run();

        verify(mockLogger).info(eq("Hello."));
    }
}
```

I chose to go with using Whitebox to outright set the static field on the class under test to my `mockLogger` instance. After that, verification was pretty straightforward.

Comment: The above code works perfectly. I tried it out. Thanks.  It does answer the question.

Comment: For some reason under spring testing I couldn't get this working until I changed the line with WhiteBox. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301635/change-private-static-final-field-using-java-reflection

Comment: I'm glad that worked for you; could you please "accept" the answer? What change did you have to make to the Whitebox line? I haven't used Spring testing with Powermock so I'm curious about the integration issues that come up.

Comment: I've "answered" that - might be useful for others.  I accepted your answer. Cheers for code. All working perfectly under spring now.

Answer (score 1):

Matt Lachman's answer worked perfectly for me - until I tried it using Spring.
In Spring, I got an runtime exception when attempting to change the logger to the
mockLogger. To get it working in Spring I had to do the following:

change the line

```
Whitebox.setInternalState(ClassUnderTest.class, "logger", mockLogger);
```

to

```
EncapsulationBreaker.setFinalStatic(ClassUnderTest.class.getDeclaredField("logger"),  mockLogger);
```

and the EncapsulationBreaker looks like this:

```
  public class EncapsulationBreaker
 {
    public static void setFinalStatic(Field field, Object newValue) throws Exception {
    field.setAccessible(true);

    Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
    modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
    modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);

    field.set(null, newValue);
 }

}
```

To read more about setting private static final members see
[Change private static final field using Java reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301635/change-private-static-final-field-using-java-reflection)

Also note, I'm only doing this for testing purposes.